# Calculate the number of operational hours of a replacement part

Tags: php, mysql

How to calculate the number of operationl hours of each part having a table with the next format ?

**MySQL table**:

```
PART | DATE FAIL  | DATE REPLACE
A    | 2018-09-22 | 2018-10-03
B    | 2018-09-04 | 2018-09-17
B    | 2018-07-06 | 2018-08-26
C    | 2018-08-19 | 2018-10-10
C    | 2018-07-23 | 2018-08-15
```

**I want the result to be like this**:

```
PART | OPERATIONAL HOURS | EVALUATION RANGE
A    | 240               | 2018-10-03 to TODAY
B    | 624               | 2018-09-17 to TODAY
B    | 216               | 2018-08-26 to 2018-09-04
C    | 72                | 2018-10-10 to TODAY
C    | 96                | 2018-08-15 to 2018-08-19
```

**Example**:

As you can note on the previous data, for example, if date of replacement of **PART B** is 2018-08-26 and the part failed next on 2018-09-04, a row like the next one should be generated on the result table:

```
PART | OPERATIONAL HOURS | EVALUATION RANGE
B    | 216               | 2018-08-26 to 2018-09-04
```

Even more, if there is not fail date posterior to a replacement date, we calculate the operatonal hours from the replacemenent date to **NOW or CURRENT DAY**

Please, help me.

Comment: i dont understand how the results are derived, what's the maths here?

Comment: Please explain the logic behind your calculation. It does not make sense. There should be a part "Install Date" also, to consider the starting date of the part usage.

Comment: And what's 'today'?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya DATE REPLACE also means install date

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT
    t1.PART,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(
        HOUR,
        t1.DATE_REPLACE,
        IFNULL(
            (SELECT MIN(DATE_FAIL) FROM oper_hours WHERE DATE_FAIL > t1.DATE_REPLACE AND PART = t1.PART),
            DATE(NOW())
        )
    ) AS OPERATIONAL_HOURS,
    CONCAT(
        t1.DATE_REPLACE,
        " to ",
        IFNULL(
            (SELECT MIN(DATE_FAIL) FROM oper_hours WHERE DATE_FAIL > t1.DATE_REPLACE AND PART = t1.PART),
            DATE(NOW())
        )
    ) AS EVALUATION_RANGE
FROM
    oper_hours AS t1
```

You can see a working example of this one here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0cc9e/7/0

As a second try (more elegant) and that include the evaluation range, you can use this one:

```
SELECT
    t1.PART,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, t1.DATE_REPLACE, IFNULL(MIN(t2.DATE_FAIL), DATE(NOW()))) AS OPERATIONAL_HOURS,
    CONCAT(t1.DATE_REPLACE, " to ", IFNULL(MIN(t2.DATE_FAIL), DATE(NOW()))) AS EVALUATION_RANGE
FROM
    oper_hours AS t1
LEFT JOIN
    oper_hours AS t2 ON t2.PART = t1.PART AND t2.DATE_FAIL > t1.DATE_REPLACE
GROUP BY
    t1.PART, t1.DATE_REPLACE
ORDER BY
    t1.PART, t1.DATE_REPLACE DESC
```

This is the resulset i got from previous query on a testing database filled with your data:

```
PART  OPERATIONAL_HOURS  EVALUATION_RANGE   
A     240                2018-10-03 to 2018-10-13
B     624                2018-09-17 to 2018-10-13
B     216                2018-08-26 to 2018-09-04
C     72                 2018-10-10 to 2018-10-13
C     96                 2018-08-15 to 2018-08-19
```

Here is a working example of this one too: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0cc9e/9

Comment: before thx for your answer @D. Smania 
i've try SELECT
    t1.PART,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(
        HOUR,
        t1.DATE_REPLACE,
        IFNULL(
            (SELECT DATE_FAIL
             FROM oper_hours
             WHERE DATE_FAIL > t1.DATE_REPLACE AND PART = t1.PART),
            DATE(NOW())
        )
    ) AS OPERATIONAL_HOURS
FROM
    oper_hours AS t1  
if the 5 record its work but it's not work when i've many data and continues to increase error  #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row why?

Comment: That is beacuse there are more than one row that match next restriction: `DATE_FAIL > t1.DATE_REPLACE AND PART = t1.PART`. I will come with a solution later. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I have updated the first query to take care of your feedback, I also added information about the evaluation range. If I found a solution for the second query, I will update it too.

Comment: Updated second query too, and added **SQLFiddle** examples, please, tellme if they have any issues now.

Comment: before thanks for your answer @D. Smania i've try your query but i still have issue if there are 2 PART with DATE_FAIL dan DATE_REPLACE are same

Comment: should be it 
PART | LOCATION | DATE FAIL | DATE REPLACE
A | AA 12.23.34 | 2018-10-01 | 2018-10-11
B | RT 23.23.67 | 2018-09-11 | 2018-09-30
B | RT 23.23.67 | 2018-08-08 | 2018-08-23
C | TT 23.45.67 | 2018-09-01 | 2018-09-12
C | YY 24.45.66 | 2018-10-01 | 2018-10-05
D | GG 12.12.45 | 2018-10-02 | 2018-10-02
D | GG 12.12.45 | 2018-10-02 | 2018-10-02

Comment: The result:
PART | LOCATION | OPERATIONAL_HOURS | EVALUATION_RANGE
A | AA 12.23.34 | 72 | 2018-10-11 to 2018-10-14
B | RT 23.23.67 | 336 | 2018-09-30 to 2018-10-14
B | RT 23.23.67 | 456 | 2018-08-23 to 2018-09-11
C | TT 23.45.67 | 768 | 2018-09-12 to 2018-10-14
C | YY 24.45.66 | 216 | 2018-10-05 to 2018-10-14
D | GG 12.12.45 | 0 | 2018-10-02 to 2018-10-02
D | GG 12.12.45 | 0 | 2018-10-02 to 2018-10-02
D | GG 12.12.45 | 288 | 2018-10-02 to 2018-10-14

sorry i forgot there is one more condition that location must be the same

Comment: Please, can you add this new requirement on your question like an update of it, is hard to understand the table format on one line. I will check this new requiremente when i have some time. Anyways, do my latests update works as expected fo you?

Comment: Ok, i have understand your new issue: you have the part named **D** that failed on date **2018-10-02**, got replaced on that day and failed again on this same day. So, you want a row that show a **zero** on the operational hours and the query i made for you don't show this. My suggestion is, to change the table schema, and use a **DATETIME** type for columns **DATE_FAIL** and **DATE_REPLACE**. Using this type will help to approximate more to reality, because a fail and a replacement on the real life can never occur on the same instant of time. If you do this, my query will work as you expect.